# LINQ to Dataset no longer recognises the "Field<string>" keyword

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset

I have some data in a dataset and I would normally select a record as shown below.

```
SnapshotDS.SnapshotRow[] previousRow = 
    m_PreviousSnapshot.Snapshot.Select(string.Format("TechKey = '{0}'", ChangeRow.TechKey)) 
        as SnapshotDS.SnapshotRow[];

ChangeRow.Prev_Staff_No = previousRow[0].Staff_No;
```

To do the same in LINQ, I would expect to do the following but I get a wiggly line under the **Field** key word.

```
var pRow = from p in m_PreviousSnapshot.Snapshot.AsEnumerable()
            where p.Field<string>("TechKey") == ChangeRow.TechKey
            .Single()
            select p;

ChangeRow.Prev_Staff_No = p.Staff_No;
```

I've used similar LINQ many times before and never had this problem.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The compiler error I get is:

> error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'string' and 'char'

... But the "TechKey field is definitely a string in the DataSet.

Comment: Select the word TechKey in the LINQ query. Press F12. What is its type?

Comment: If I press F12 with the TechKey highlighted I get a sealed class String displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to add a reference to [System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552414.aspx).

The missing methods are actually [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386916.aspx).

Also change:

```
var pRow = from p in m_PreviousSnapshot.Snapshot.AsEnumerable()
        where p.Field<string>("TechKey") == ChangeRow.TechKey
        .Single()
        select p;
```

to:

```
var pRows = from p in m_PreviousSnapshot.Snapshot.AsEnumerable()
        where p.Field<string>("TechKey") == ChangeRow.TechKey
        select p;
var pRow = pRows.Single();
```

The .Single() (where you had it) is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: I have a project reference to "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" and I'm also "using System.Data;".

Comment: Great stuff. It was the "Single" statement that was the problem... And you were right, it wasn't doing what I expected and in actual fact I wanted to use "First".  :o)